# Read from database every time a new record goes through a Spark pipeline

Tags: data, data-cleaning, pyspark, pipelines, data-engineering

I'm using Spark to filter and transform every new record that goes through a data stream, the problem is that for each new record I need to read a table from a Cassandra database in order to have the necessary data to label this new record.

This is the code where I call the `writeStream` object to filter each new row and will execute the `label_row` function each time:

```
stream = spark.readStream.option("header", True).schema(schema).csv("/path/to/my/csv")
query = stream.writeStream.foreach(label_row).outputMode("update").start().awaitTermination()
```

And this is the portion of the code inside `label_row` function where I read the database:

```
...
all_previous_records = session.execute("SELECT * FROM keyspaceX.tableY where group_id = "+record.group_id)
current_record_label = 0
if len(all_previous_records) < threshold_x:
   current_record_label = 1
elif len(all_previous_records) < threshold_y:
   current_record_label = 2 
...
if current_record_label == 1:
   session.execute("INSERT INTO keyspaceX.tableY(fieldA,fieldB,group_id) VALUES fieldA="+record.fieldA+",fieldB="+record.fieldB+",group_id="+record.group_id)
elif current_record_label == 2:
   session.execute("INSERT INTO keyspaceX.tableZ(fieldB,group_id) VALUES fieldB="+record.fieldB+",group_id="+record.group_id)
...
```

As you can notice in the code above, the table `tableY` is read and updated for every new record, so, if a new record comes it will be affected by the update of previous records. I was wondering if this approach is okay.